# IndexError: list index out of range.The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application

Tags: python

```
elif Username == data[1]:
    balance += float(data[2])
```

the problem is showing on "elif" line

```
def get_balance(Username):
    balance = 0.00
    blockchain = get_blockchain()
```

and this code is to get the balance

Comment: Please edit your question with your full relevant code sample.

Comment: #loop through the blockchain and update balance
    for block in blockchain.chain:
        data = block.data.split("-->")
        if Username == data[0]:
            balance -= float(data[2])

        elif Username == data[1]:
            balance += float(data[2])

Comment: what is `blockchain.chain` and what will be in `data` for each iteration ?

Comment: when i give amount from bank to any user it suppose to show in my system that this user has this amount of money..im getting the result from my database but my app is not showing anything like that